# How to read a file that is part of the solution on program load?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm writing a C# WinForms application, and one of the components of the application is a SQLite database.

If the user is running the program for the first time, the program is supposed to create the necessary folders and files (namely, the database file) in the user's home directory. That works fine.

However, the database also needs to be set up (i.e., tables need to be added). I have a SQL script that will create the necessary tables; however, it is currently stored in the solution directory and I'm not sure if this is the best practice for when the program actually gets packaged into an .exe file.

The script will be the same every time the database needs to be set up, so I'm thinking there are probably a few options:

- Have the program read from the SQL script and apply it to the database (preferred unless there is a better way)
- Load the contents of the script file into memory (hard-code it into a `string`) and have the application run it that way (not preferred because of future versions, there needs to be a way to update the existing structure so as to not obliterate the existing database, so this way could get complicated)
- Include the SQL script as part of the program package or a standalone file (very dangerous because users aren't supposed to know about that)

So what is the best way to run SQL statements from a "companion" script file? How does all of this get packaged when the program is ready for production, and how can I ensure that this file will be accessible by the program every time it is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the file to be copied in output directory. Select the file in solution explorer and then in property window, set [*Copy to Output Directory*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2) to *Copy Always*. This way the file will be copied in output directory and you can load it this way:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Script.txt");
var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

If the file in root of the solution, use filename as above. If the file is in a folder in your solution, for example for a file in Folder1, use `@"Folder1\Script.txt"` in above code.

As another option you can add the file to `Resources.resx`. Then it will be included in resources and you can simply access it this way:

```
var content = Properties.Resources.Script;
```

Comment: @DavidMordigal, If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Comment: @Lahiru my bad, I left it because you have to wait a while until you can accept an answer and I completely forgot

Answer (score 0):

Include an encrypted version of the sql file. Have your program load, decrypt it then execute it. At least that's how I'd do it.